# Invoke a native statement on obtaining connection in entity manager

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish

My company is using database ONINSERT, ONUPDATE, ONDELETE triggers for logging changes and there is also a way to impersonate another database user by calling a stored procedure which sets a database session parameter. Then any changes made with that connection are automatically assigned to that user. I know it is a bad design but I cannot change this.

Now I need to make sure this stored procedure is always called before entity manager synchronizes changes with database and the user to impersonate is different each time. I tried simply doing it by simply wrapping the stored procedure call in a stateless EJB and calling that EJB before I make any changes to entities but this does not work in some cases - it acts like the procedure was never called. My guess is that the procedure was called in a different connection than the changes themselves were posted although this was supposed to happen in a single transaction.

Is there any clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use EntityListeners.  These would have to be put on all your Entities, so if you have a lot, maybe it's not a good solution.

Otherwise, you may need an implementation specific way:

- Toplink: http://java-persistence.blogspot.com/2007/04/simple-auditing-using-toplink-jpa.html
- Hibernate: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AuditLogging
- EclipseLink: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=165280&#page_top